# Can I connect to a private app using XeroCoreApi without a pfx file?

Tags: xero-api

I've inherited a system which I'm rewriting in .Net Core.
The current system uses [xero-node](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node) to make requests to Xero.

Xero-node makes use of the .pem file for authentication.

I'm using [Xero-NetStandard](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard) but this requires a pfx.  I have a pfx but don't have a password for it.  I have the .pem but I can't seem to use it with this api.

Is it possible to use the .pem file with the Xero lib?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you need to use the pfx. Do you have the option of re-generating the certificate and uploading it to Xero to generate a new key/secret pair?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've gone down the route of regenerating the certs for the clients test system and can connect fine.  Looks like I will have to do that for the live system also.